# Windows Security Error from Jaspersoft Studio 6.3.1 final

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

I am receiving a Windows security dialog box when attempting to run a report on a remote server through Jaspersoft Studio. I have done a lot of searching for answers but haven't found anything. Anyone have any ideas of the issue? The remote server is running on Linux, Tomcat6, Jaspersoft Studio installed on WIndows 10, Community Edition of Studio.

This is the dialogue window that comes up in Windows.

[image: Windows dialogue]

Comment: You simply have to be authenticated to connect to the server.

Comment: I am authenticated through Jasper Studio Server Connection. You mean I have to have a user account on the host machine as well?

Comment: There can be also some issues with the server config, since it's an ordinary HTTP auth prompt. Maybe there is another authentication in-line?